# asp.net 4.0 chart control

Tags: c#, asp.net, charts, web-config

I have some weird problem with my asp.net charting control.

Everything is working fine on my locale machine but when I load my project to my website host, sometimes the images appear and sometimes they don't (resource not found).

this from my web.config:

appSettings

```
add key="ChartImageHandler" value="Storage=file;Timeout=20;~\TempImages\"/
```

/appSettings

I also tried putting it on the session and with longer timeout but nothing helps (it happends on all major browsers)

I have read and write permissions on TempImages folder

If you have any suggestions it would be great

Thanks

Doron

Answer (score 0):

Do your charts require any bitmaps/backgrounds or other things that may not be getting loaded in time or are in use by another process?  If so, try making a plain chart.

Is the data always available?

BTW:  The default time out is 30, not 20 (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd456629.aspx)

Comment: There is nothing special in those charts, just plain ones, the data is available at all time and i already tried extending the timeout

Comment: Are you sure the message is from the chart control and not another part of your program?

Comment: There is no message, the picture doesn't come up and the page left blank, I opened firebug console and saw that there is 404 on that picture

Comment: You are going to have to add debug/log strings in the code that builds the chart to see where the failure is.  You're not hiding exceptions and errors are you?  (Like:  catch {}).